# jQuery $.getJSON: "Failed to load resource: cancelled"

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, jquery-mobile

I'm having problem loading a json resource from a local rails app with jQuery 1.4.4

The json is valid (based on jsonlint.com) and I can download it properly if I'm requesting it from other sources.

In webkit (Safari), I got this error:

```
Failed to load resource: cancelled
```

Response Header on Firebug:

```
Content-Type application/json; charset=utf-8
Set-Cookie geoloc=toulouse; path=/;
Connection close
Server thin 1.2.7 codename No Hup
```

jQuery code to load json:

```
$.getJSON("http://127.0.0.1/search_agenda",
  {'edition': edition,
  'categories': categories},
  function(data){
    console.log(data);
  }
});
```

Comment: this doesn't seem to have anything to do with jquery mobile. retagging

Comment: I don't think this is your problem (at least from the example) but if a page requests a Url via AJAX while there's already a request to that Url pending, the new request is allowed to continue and the pending request(s) are cancelled.

Answer (score 1):

Your getJSON seems correct to me.

I had the same error. And it actually is due to jquery mobile. I haven't gotten to the bottom of it, but basically I get this error even if I just include the jquery mobile libraries in a blank html page.

I suspect that the jquery.js and jquery_mobile.js are incompatible versions. I will check back when I find out the real reason.

Comment: All right, the problem is definitely with the jquery_mobile library. In my case, I didn't need it badly, so I just excluded the bloody thing. For this particular call, you don't need jquery mobile either.

Comment: BTW, screwup is with 1.0a4.1 version of the jquery mobile.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that you're loading the page from http://127.0.0.1/ in your browser too. Anyway, it's always a better option to use relative paths.

Comment: AFAIK this error is always related to a cross-domain request. Try to laod your page from http://localhost/ instead of http://127.0.0.1/, even if it doesn't make any sense. Could you provide more details?

Answer (score 0):

try putting a relative path. Ajax calls are forbidden between different domains, so your browser may think that your app is on the `localhost` domain and the request is in a different one (`127.0.0.1`).

If this is the case, you can try something like :

```
$.getJSON("http://" + location.host + "/search_agenda",
  {'edition': edition,
  'categories': categories},
  function(data){
    console.log(data);
  }
);
```